# SharePoint 2013 Web Parts and Apps

Tags: web-part, 2013, app

Does SharePoint 2013 support Web Parts or only new Apps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to traditional web parts still being supported (in either full-trust or sandboxed solutions) as Simon mentions, you can develop new **app parts** in an app for SharePoint 2013.

An app part is like a web part, and in fact is also made available to users in a host web's web part gallery. Users add app parts to pages the same way they would add web parts. One fundamental difference between an app part and a web part is that an app part uses an IFRAME to load the app part's content.

App parts, like web parts, can also have custom properties that users can set. More information about this, and app part development in general, may be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179921.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, very helpful answer and link. I have resolved all questions, related to Web Parts and Apps.

Comment: What if the host web is a subsite? Doesn't only root sites have a web part gallery? If I install an app with app parts in it, will it be available to all webs in the site collection?

Answer (score 2):

> SharePoint 2013 Introduced App Model  Because of Software Market tends
>   And Manage Solution without disturbing other tenants Especially in
>   Online or Cloud scenarios. To meet this goal Microsoft Provide Great
>   App Model for Developer to Build Apps on top of the SharePoint 2013.
>   But mostly developer is used to develop their solution for Cloud by
>   using visual WebPart in sandbox solution and farm based solution with
>   visual webpart for on permission online sharepoint.  App Model quit
>   bit similar from sandbox solution. But still are few recitations and
>   changes between SharePoint WebPart and SharePoint Apps.  As a
>   Developer feel bit restricted in this Model.As I like same felt same
>   previously when 2010 sandbox . But it more secure as well because of
>   any developer mistake it will not going to damage my SharePoint Site
>   or Farm.
>
> Difference  between WebPart and SharePoint App.
>
> 1. OFFICE 356 AND MOST LIKE OTHER ONLINE SOLUTION FOR SharePoint would not allow Farm based Solution for web-Parts.
> 2. Web Part has capability to use SharePoint Core Object by using code behind.
> 3. There is no code behind in SharePoint Apps. Especially for office 356 you create your solution without disturbing other tenant.
> 4. You can create lists, libraries and other SharePoint Component.
> 5. App have its own site-collection Site-Collection where app stores its list and data.
> 6. SharePoint 2013 we have App Parts like Web Parts. App Part runs in IFrame by using the click jack technique.
> 7. The app runs in IFrame that why they cannot assess DOM. ITS HTML restriction. But it's really very cool feature if you app has some bed
>      it will not disturb your site.
> 8. If your app required any Service like the BCS. YOU HAVE TO ALLOW PERMISSION IN VS ON DEPLOYMENT TIME. WHEN USER WILL ADD APP. IT
>      REQUIRED PERMISSION FROM USER TO ALLOW HIM TO ASSESS. THAT components
>      OF SERVICE. LIKE books, stoical, taxonomy, Project, Reporting, List
>      and Manage Rights Full Control., Read, Write, Managed. Give Specific
>      Permissions for your apps. ReadMore
> 9. SharePoint App has Page which Asp.net ASPX page where app actually start-up page for the app.
> 10. SharePoint also keeps its Assets with it. Like JavaScript and Images.
> 11. SharePoint 2013 App Features have only Web-scoped only for deployment.
> 12. SharePoint 2013 Web templates are available .But not site definitions.
>
> Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179930.aspx

[Source](http://usamawahabkhan.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/sharepoint-2013-apps-vs-webparts-for.html)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is a extremely helpful in combination with Simon's clarification.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2013 still supports Web Parts.

Comment: I'm not sure this adds much to the previous answer (other than a little clarity).

Comment: The second answer doesnt actually answer the question.

Comment: It does in a roundabout way. The fact that web parts are still supported is mentioned indirectly by the quote, but is admittedly a bit of a dense read. Personally (and this is a personal preference) I would have either commented on the previous answer or added a bit more detail to my own, such as an external reference.

Comment: Fair enough, I just thought simple question, simple answer ;)